# How to get all the DrugList

Tags: api, data.gov, openfda, json

I want to fetch all the drugList, lets say -> `DrugName`, `Manufacturer`, `Prescribed for`, `Description`.
I tried using `https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?count=patient.drug.openfda.manufacturer_name.exact` It jst fetch the high level manufacturer name now to fetch the In-depth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current OpenFDA Adverse Event dataset isn't really well suited for a query like that. An API for the drug SPLs (Structured Product Labels) is coming soon according to https://open.fda.gov/about/ though.

For now, check out the following resources for the data you're looking for:

- NLM Pillbox API (http://pillbox.nlm.nih.gov) - recommended - most developer friendly
- NIH DailyMed bulk downloads and APIs (http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/help.cfm#webservices)
- FDA National Drug Code Directory bulk download and web search (http://www.fda.gov/drugs/informationondrugs/ucm142438.htm)

Comment: Mark, Which one will you suggest if I want to use `DrugName`, `Drug Description`, `Manufacturer`, `Drug Image`, along with `Side Effects`. I tried to look at all API but I can't find everything at one request.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar - not being able to get it all in one API call is pretty much the situation at this moment. You might also want to look at http://mor.nlm.nih.gov/RxMix/ ... 
If you want more 1:1 help, you can definitely contact me privately as this is what I do for a living.

Comment: Mark what is best contact for you? phone number ?
we are working on the project and it will be easier if we will speak 1:1 then we can figure out what is needed to go forward.

Comment: @Orest : If you have additional questions, it's best to ask it in a new question, as there may be someone else who can answer.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar - my email is mark@socialhealthinsights.com. Pretty new to posting here on SE so hopefully I'm allowed to post my own personal info for off-SE conversations.

Comment: Sorry @Orest - that last comment of mine was meant for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to use the [drugbank database](https://www.drugbank.ca/) of drugnames . They are more upto dates. I played with the [NLM pillbox data](http://pillbox.nlm.nih.gov) found some names like venetoclax doesn't even listed. Drugbank drug names are more generic.

Comment: Hi welcome to OpenData. Do you have URLs that you could include in your answer, which would improve your answer?