# Get All medicine names

Tags: openfda

My aim is to give intelligent support to the textbox where the user will type the medicine name that they want, and I will provide suggestions of the medicine.

For this purpose, i want to get the list of all names of medicines from OpenFDA.

I am able to retrieve the particular medicine details from their site, by using this query:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?api_key=yourAPIKeyHere&search=patient.drug.medicinalproduct:Crocin

But, I am unable to get all the details of the medication.

I have also seen this [link](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3213/how-to-get-all-the-druglist), and have been told to use this API all alone and not any other API.

Could someone help me to understand how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: As I mentioned in https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3213/how-to-get-all-the-druglist, OpenFDA isn't well suited for this. is there a particular reason you are forcing yourself to use OpenFDA instead of Pillbox, NLM MedlinePlus, or NIH DailyMed?

Comment: Sorry. It is my manager decision. I cannot act against it..!!!!!!!

Comment: That's quite funny (read: unfortunate) because of all the data sources, openFDA has the most disclaimers and caveats to use (see https://open.fda.gov/terms/). I would highly suggest DailyMed for this.

Comment: i developed a example here: https://jsfiddle.net/romanlezama/jqxrgo3n/ this work fine for me.
I hope this help you @NANDAKUMAR

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) Can you place the actual answer **here**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for some reason, you must use openFDA for this use case, you could go ahead and [page through](https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/#query-parameters) the following API call:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?count=openfda.brand_name.exact&limit=1000

However, this isn't too helpful because brand_names are duplicated so you would then have to have the user specify, somehow, which record they want (or maybe you can make some sort of assumption).

Answer (score 1):

i developed an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/romanlezama/jqxrgo3n/). This worked fine for me.
I hope this helps you @NANDAKUMAR.

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) Can you place the actual answer **here**?

Comment: your example is not working